# Tomee dynamic Resources/Datasources

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

After searching for a while, I'm exhausted and hope you can help me. I've been trying to write a Java EE application that comes with a datasource configurator (like WordPress at first startup). The `datasources` are not known on deploy time. With the router example of [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/examples/dynamic-datasource-routing.html) I found a method to dynamically replace `datasources` at application lifetime. I'm currently generating my `datasources` with the following code:

```
 GeronimoTransactionManager transactionManager = (GeronimoTransactionManager) OpenEJB.getTransactionManager();

 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("driverClassName", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
 props.setProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
 props.setProperty("password", "test");
 props.setProperty("passwordCipher", "PlainText");
 props.setProperty("username", "test");

 try {
     DataSource underlying = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory().createDataSource(props);
     dataSource = new ManagedDataSource(underlying, transactionManager, transactionManager);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

My problem is that at this point no `ddl-generation` is executed, so that `entitymanager.persist(object);` throws an exception that the table was not generated.

The following code produces an `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`:

```
Map properties = new HashMap<>();

StringWriter create = new StringWriter();

properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action", "create");
properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target", create);

Persistence.generateSchema("router", properties);
```

Is there a not "hacky" Java EE way to dynamically load resources, especially `datasources`. If not, is there a TomEE way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to hack JEE?

Comment: can you register multiple datasources in tomee.xml and then when you load the entitymanager you choose the datasource.  e.g. http://www.hostettler.net/blog/2012/11/20/multi-tenancy/